# what API should i use to lock and unlock screen in MAC OS X?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

Can you tell me what API and function should i try to use to make an application that will lock and unlock screen using the dialog box in MAC OS X?

Answer (score 1):

Triggering the screensaver isn't that hard, but you can't override the unlock behavior (one big reason is security).

Thus, you'll probably have to roll your own solution by running an application in "kiosk mode".

Google for "Mac OS X Kiosk Mode" should get you started (I haven't done kiosk apps for Mac OS X, not since it was called OpenStep 4.2, anyway).